# Fabric.js - how to save canvas on server with custom attributes

Tags: database, json, savechanges, fabricjs

I'd like to be able to save the current canvas' state to a server-side database, probably as a JSON string, and then later restore it with `loadFromJSON`. Typically, this is easily accomplished using:

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas();
function saveCanvas() {
    // convert canvas to a json string
    var json = JSON.stringify( canvas.toJSON() );

    // save via xhr
    $.post('/save', { json : json }, function(resp){ 
        // do whatever ...
    }, 'json');
}
```

And then

```
function loadCanvas(json) {

  // parse the data into the canvas
  canvas.loadFromJSON(json);

  // re-render the canvas
  canvas.renderAll();

  // optional
  canvas.calculateOffset();
}
```

However, I've also been setting a few custom attributes on the fabric objects I'm adding to the canvas using the builtin `Object#set` method:

```
// get some item from the canvas
var item = canvas.item(0);

// add misc properties
item.set('wizard', 'gandalf');
item.set('hobbit', 'samwise');

// save current state
saveCanvas();
```

The problem is that when I check the request on the server-side, I see that my custom attributes were not parsed from the canvas and sent along with everything else. This probably has to do with how `toObject` method removes anything that's not a default attribute in the object class. What would be a good way to tackle this issue, such that I'll be able to both save **and** restore the canvas from a JSON string sent by the server, and the restored canvas will also include my custom attributes? thanks.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Good question.

If you're adding custom properties to objects, those objects are likely "special" in some way. It seems like subclassing them would be a reasonable solution.

For example, here's how we would subclass a `fabric.Image` into a named image. Those image objects could then have names like "Gandalf" or "Samwise".

```
fabric.NamedImage = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Image, {

  type: 'named-image',

  initialize: function(element, options) {
    this.callSuper('initialize', element, options);
    options && this.set('name', options.name);
  },

  toObject: function() {
    return fabric.util.object.extend(this.callSuper('toObject'), { name: this.name });
  }
});
```

First, we give these objects a type. This type is used by `loadFromJSON` to automatically invoke `fabric.<type>.fromObject` method. In this case it would be `fabric.NamedImage.fromObject`.

Then we overwrite `initialize` (constructor) instance method, to also set "name" property when initializing an object (if that property is given).

Then we overwrite `toObject` instance method to include "name" in returned object (this is a cornerstone of object serialization in fabric).

Finally, we'll also need to implement that `fabric.NamedImage.fromObject` that I mentioned earlier, so that `loadFromJSON` would know which method to invoke during JSON parsing:

```
fabric.NamedImage.fromObject = function(object, callback) {
  fabric.util.loadImage(object.src, function(img) {
    callback && callback(new fabric.NamedImage(img, object));
  });
};
```

We're loading an image here (from "object.src"), then creating an instance of `fabric.NamedImage` out of it. Note how at that point, constructor will already take care of "name" setting, since we overwrote "initialize" method earlier.

And we'll also need to specify that `fabric.NamedImage` is an asynchronous "class", meanining that its `fromObject` does not return an instance, but passes it to a callback:

```
fabric.NamedImage.async = true;
```

And now we can try this all out:

```
// create image element
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = 'https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png';

// create an instance of named image
var namedImg = new fabric.NamedImage(img, { name: 'foobar' });

// add it to canvas
canvas.add(namedImg);

// save json
var json = JSON.stringify(canvas);

// clear canvas
canvas.clear();

// and load everything from the same json
canvas.loadFromJSON(json, function() {

  // making sure to render canvas at the end
  canvas.renderAll();

  // and checking if object's "name" is preserved
  console.log(canvas.item(0).name);
});
```

Comment: Actually, I'm getting an error when trying to load the canvas back from the JSON string. I'm using `canvas.loadFromDatalessJSON(json)`, which previously worked with `fabric.Image`. Now that I'm using the `fabric.NamedImage` as suggested above, I get `cannot call method 'setupState' of undefined`. How can I fix this?

Comment: Seems to be a bug in `toDatalessJSON` :/ We have some duplicating logic in toJSON and toDatalessJSON and I want to rewrite all that, making it nice, clean, and consistent. Will do sometime in a near future.

Comment: Regardless of the current implementation, seems like I was actually messing things up myself - see this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11298971/187907

Comment: The chapter on serialization (http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-3/#serialization) could be updated with this. The existing text has bugs (e.g. doesn't store subclass in fabric object, doesn't use hyphenated type strings).

Comment: Check out @kangax's other answer to a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19444196/in-fabricjs-how-would-i-modify-the-object-class-so-all-sub-classes-will-have-a-n

Comment: @kangax, this is really cool but I'm struggling to do the same thing (add a name) to a subclass of `fabric.Group` it seems to work up to the point where I can save the JSON but when loading I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'async' of undefined` I'm pretty new to JS and so have probably got the `fromObject();` wrong. would you happen to know the signature for this?

Comment: ok I've sorted that (it was the format of my `type:` but I now have a different problem asshown here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23076344/fabric-js-uncaught-typeerror-undefined-is-not-a-function-when-loading-a-subclas

Comment: Doesn't work for PathGroup - issue described here: https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/1826. Without the 'type', the wrong fromObject gets called and we don't get the custom property.

Comment: @kangax, if you want to create a new filter, should you apply it to NamedImage or Image? I can't get JSON.stringify(canvas) to work when my custom filter is applied to Image.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! That worked for me.
I have extended `fabric.Image` with own class, and was struggling with proper serializaion/deserialization.

Can anyone expalin  why `fabric.util.loadImage()` works, but  `fabric.Image.fromObject()` was failing?

It throwed error, trying to access `src` property of of undefined `originalelement`

Comment: I had created Custom Line Object `GridLine` and  by returning `{}` from `toObject()`, I was able to keep away the Objects from history states.

Answer (score 23):

Wow. Am I missing something here?

I've done this plenty of times and it doesn't need any fancy subclassing.

The docs cover it: http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#toJSON

Just include an array of property names as strings in your call to toJSON().

Eg

```
canvas.toJSON(['wizard','hobbit']);
```

Hopefully.... for bonus points you can add a reviver function which will rehydrate your custom attributes.

Again this is covered in the docs and has an example.

Comment: I now realise this question is 6 years old LOL. Anyway I hope it helps anyone stumbling across it.

Comment: for me, canvas.toJSON returned an object, not a string. I had to also call JSON.stringify.

Comment: I was facing the same issue and this solution works for me. I am getting the properties I have added in the array. Thank @kbcool

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue but I didn't want to extend the fabric.js classes.

I wrote a function that takes the fabric canvas in parameter and returns a stringified version with my special attributes:

```
function stringifyCanvas(canvas)
{
    //array of the attributes not saved by default that I want to save
    var additionalFields = ['selectable', 'uid', 'custom']; 

    sCanvas = JSON.stringify(canvas);
    oCanvas = JSON.parse(sCanvas) ;
    $.each(oCanvas.objects, function(n, object) {
        $.each(additionalFields, function(m, field) {
            oCanvas.objects[n][field] = canvas.item(n)[field];
        });
    });

    return JSON.stringify(oCanvas);     
}
```

The special attributes seems properly imported when I use `canvas.loadFromJSON()`, I'm using fabric `1.7.2`.

Answer (score 2):

A more simple approach would be to add the properties post-stringify:

```
var stringJson = JSON.stringify(this.canvas);
var objectJson = JSON.parse(string.Json);

//remove property1 property
delete objectJson.property1;

//add property2 property
delete objectJson.property2;

// stringify the object again
stringJson = JSON.stringify(objectJson);

// at this point stringJson is ready to be sent over to the server
$http.post('http://serverurl/',stringJson);
```

Comment: The inverse should work without any problems: https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/471

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to specify the custom attributes you are using every time you call `canvas.toJSON()`, and you don't want to use a complicated subclassing approach, here is a very simple way to extend Fabric's `toObject` method.

```
//EXTEND THE PROPS FABRIC WILL EXPORT TO JSON
fabric.Object.prototype.toObject = (function(toObject) {
    return function() {
        return fabric.util.object.extend(toObject.call(this), {
            id: this.id,
            wizard: this.wizard,
            hobbit: this.hobbit,
        });
    };
})(fabric.Object.prototype.toObject);
```

Then you can set custom properties on Fabric objects.

```
item.set("wizard","gandalf");
item.set("hobbit","bilbo");
```

And when you call `canvas.toJSON()` those properties will persist to the output. If you then use `canvas.loadFromJSON()` with your JSON output, the custom attributes will be imported and applied to the Fabric objects.

Answer (score 0):

http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-3#serialization

```
var rect = new fabric.Rect();

rect.toObject = (function(toObject) {
  return function() {
    return fabric.util.object.extend(toObject.call(this), {
      name: this.name
    });
  };
})(rect.toObject);

canvas.add(rect);

rect.name = 'trololo';

console.log(JSON.stringify(canvas));
```