# FabricJS - Error when loading Canvas from JSON

Tags: json, canvas, load, fabricjs

I'm using a custom object extended from `fabric.Image` in my canvas, as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11276133/187907). When I retrieve the json string from the server, I get odd errors when attempting to load it to the canvas:

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvsd();

function loadCanvas(resp) {
  // response object contains a data field
  // that's essentialy a JSON string
  var json = JSON.parse(resp.data);
  canvas.loadFromDatalessJSON(json);
}
```

I get an odd printout to the console: `Cannot call method 'setupState' of undefined   (fabric.min.js: 1118)`. I tried replacing the call with `canvas.loadFromJSON(json)`, and instead got a vague `SyntaxError: Unexpected token o` error. When I used a regular `fabric.Image` before the change suggested in the linked thread, this code worked fine. I fear this might be something I'm missing when I extended favric's Image class with aditional data. Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some search I saw a [similar thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/fabricjs/Am5_6w2D13w) in the fabricjs google group. Turned out I  messing up 3 things:

1. I was missing a `fromObject()` callback definition in a different location for another custom object I made (I had a couple).
2. I was using `loadFromDatalessJSON()` when I should have been using simply `loadFromJSON()`.
3. I was parsing the json string into an actual JSON using `JSON.parse(json)` before passing it into the `loadFromJSON()` function, which expected a json string and handled the parsing internally.

Derp.