# In Fabric.js how do I modify the object class so all sub-classes will have a new custom attribute?

Tags: javascript, canvas, prototype, fabricjs

I am looking for a way to extend the base fabric.Object class with a custom attribute I can save to JSON and load from JSON that would propagate all the way into the various sub classes.

Specifically i want to store a depth attribute so when i load the objects from the JSON i will be able to add the appropriate parallax to the object.

I imagine the solution would include modifying the fabric.Object.prototype. But i am still learning how to work with prototypes.

Here is some examples of what i have tried:
http://www.sitepoint.com/fabric-js-advanced/

```
// create a rectangle object
var rect = new fabric.Rect({
    left: 100,
    top: 100,
    fill: 'red',
    width: 20,
    height: 20
});

rect.toObject = (function (toObject) {
    return function () {
        return fabric.util.object.extend(toObject.call(this), {
            depth: 10
        });
    };
})(rect.toObject);
```

This does a great job at giving the specific object 'rect' the attribute desired, as well as making it available in the `toJSON()` method. But it fails to make it available for all objects and when i use `loadFromJSON()` it does not contain the new attribute.

Any help would be appreciated!

Other resources that got me closer to a solution:
[Fabric.js - how to save canvas on server with custom attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11272772/fabricjs-how-to-save-canvas-on-server-with-custom-attributes) 
 - Creates a subclass with the custom attributes but nothing inherits from it.
https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/wiki/Adding-additional-object-properties-to-serialized-JSON 
 - completely rewrites the methods needed in order to include custom attributes (I would prefer not to modify the core of fabricjs)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The simplest way would be to just specify which properties you'd like included when calling `toJSON`:

```
canvas.toJSON([ 'selectable', 'lockMovementX' ]);
```

But if you want to really-really add them to the output, you can monkey-patch `fabric.Object.prototype.toObject` the same way it's done with rectangle:

```
fabric.Object.prototype.toObject = (function (toObject) {
    return function () {
        return fabric.util.object.extend(toObject.call(this), {
            foobar: 123
        });
    };
})(fabric.Object.prototype.toObject);
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thanks! I ended up using your monkey-patch because I can then manipulate the new attribute as well as save them.

Comment: How can one pass an argument to 'foobar' in this example?

Comment: fabric.Object.prototype.toObject = (function (toObject) {
            return function () {
                return fabric.util.object.extend(toObject.call(this), {
                    anim: this.anim
                });
            };
        })(fabric.Object.prototype.toObject);

Comment: var o = canvas.getActiveObject();
o.anim = 'blink';

Comment: It works perfectly, but what if I want to add custom properties only to certain objects?