# Object's custom properties getting cleared in canvas to json

Tags: javascript, json, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I have a canvas with multiple `image objects`. Every object has some custom attributes. I need to save this canvas as a json object into a database. I used following code to convert canvas into json.

```
canvasJson = JSON.stringify(canvas);
```

After converting, `canvasJson` can't have any custom attribute as well as  it's values. It has only default attributes and it's values like width, height, opacity etc.

How can I fix that? Please suggest some right ways to solve this...

**Edit**

Following is my image object creation code to create image objects in canvas.

```
var imgObj = new Image();
var imgSrc = $IMAGE_URL;
imgObj.src = imgSrc;
var image = new fabric.Image(imgObj);
    image.set({
        left: 0,
        top: 0,
        angle: 0,
        padding: 0,
        cornersize: 0,
        lockMovementX: true,
        lockMovementY: true,
        lockRotation: true,
        elementId: $elementID,
        elementname: $elementName,
        elementstatus: $elementStatus,
        width: componentImageWidth,
        height: componentImageHeight
    });
    canvas.add(image);
    image.setCoords();
    canvas.renderAll();
    canvas.selection = false;
    canvas.renderAll();
    setObjectAction(image, false);
```

Converting the canvas into json using `JSON.stringify(canvas);` the `elementId`, `elementname` and `elementstatus` are missing. but default attributes are gets correctly.

How to fix this ?

Comment: Please add your complete code snippet or create JSFiddle to elaborate more.

Comment: Show us your canvas object.

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: I have added elementid, elementname, elemetstatus as custom attributes for all image objects while creating it. Now i want to get my custom attributes also json object

Comment: It's too large code so i can't add show here @CharlieH

Comment: Its difficult to say why your canvas object is not converted to json well without looking at it.

Comment: See my edit @CharlieH

Comment: you have to extend the fabric.Image class.Probably this one will help. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11272772/fabric-js-how-to-save-canvas-on-server-with-custom-attributes/11276133#11276133]

Answer (score 6):

You can use fabric's canvas.toJson() or canvas.toDatalessJSON() functions, and you can include your custom properties as parameters like this:

```
var json = JSON.stringify(canvas.toDatalessJSON(['elementId','elementname', 'elementstatus']));
```

Comment: How about loading?