# Fabric.js canvas not catching mouse:down event on image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I have simple HTML page including some css styles, j query, jquery-ui and obviously Fabric.js.Now i want to draw line between two images while moving mouse. Although itś working absolutely fine when i start dragging mouse from just below image but if i start dragging from image then mouse:down event is not working. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qb7Jv.png)

Comment: Can you make a snippet/fiddle stating your issue?

Comment: i  have attached image

Comment: Check [this](http://fabricjs.com/stickman)

Comment: thanks for the help.. but mine case is bit different as i have to draw line between two or let's say three images.. n at the same time i am able to draw line also but when i click on the image and then start drawing then it's not working.. Actually what i can from code is that mouse:down event is not working when we click on any image..

Comment: `mouse:down` will work if the image is selected and evented, I am not able to get what might be the problem, if possible make a fiddle stating the issue.

Comment: You have to add that image on canvas so you can click through that, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36975511/3551786)

Comment: i am not getting exactly when to add image to canvas and also i want line between two images and not on images..so can please share a piece of code where we can draw line between two images..Also line starts drawing even if we click on image then move our mouse..